# Issue with Croatian keyboard layout on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, and selected Croatian layout during setup, and it was working without issue for almost half a day, and then out of nowhere my 'v' key stopped working. This are some facts that I managed to realize:

- shift + v - works
- ctrl + v - works
- altgr + v - doesn't work
- works in ubuntu search bar, but not in any other application
- when I add and use english layout - still doesn't work
- but when I remove Croatian layout and there is only English layout - it works fine

If someone can help and explain how to re-install or somehow reset keyboard layout for Croatian keyboard, or if there is something else I can try? I have googled this issue for past few hours, and nothing I tried helped ex:

- typing assist is disabled
- ubuntu is up to date with all packages
- tried different keyboard, etc.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: A first thing I would try is to reinstall the package with the layouts: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Are you sure it's not an intermittent hardware problem? Try also the Bosnian keyboard layout which is probably the same.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson comment worked for me. You should put it as answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - thanks that seems to do the trick!